# How to remove the empty list in the Series, and at the same time change the non-empty list into a string form?

Tags: python, string, series

The following is an example

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'AAA','BBBB','CCC'},columns=['fruit'])
a=pd.Series({'0':'A','1':'B','2':'C'})
dict_a={}
for x in a:
dict_a[x]=''.join('%s' %a for a in filter(None,df['fruit'].str.findall(r'.*{}.*'.format(x))))
```

The dictionary values I get are in list form：['AAA'],['BBB'] but my ideal form is：'AAA','BBB'
How to remove the empty list in the Series, and at the same time change the non-empty list into a string form,I want to use it as the value of the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only the 1st element of the match, take the list item at index 0:

```
for x in a:
    dict_a[x] = ''.join(m[0] for m in filter(None, df['fruit'].str.findall(r'.*{}.*'.format(x))))

# `dict_a` is:
{'A': 'AAA', 'B': 'BBBB', 'C': 'CCC'}
```

This will take only the first result of `findall` which might not give the results you want if you have more than one match in the dataframe or more than one match per row in the dataframe.

(Also, don't reuse the series name `a` in your loop. I've change it to `m`.)